# NHibernate query with Projections.Cast to DateTime

Tags: .net, database, nhibernate, casting

I'm experimenting with using a string for storing different kind of data types in a database. When I do queries I need to cast the strings to the right type in the query itself. I'm using .Net with NHibernate, and was glad to learn that there exists functionality for this.

For the example I'm using this simple class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I successfully use Projections.Cast to cast to numeric values, e.g. the following query correctly returns all Foos with an integer stored as int - between 1-10.

```
var result = Session.CreateCriteria<Foo>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Between(Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.Int32, Projections.Property("Text")), 1, 10))
    .List<Foo>();
```

Now if I try using this for DateTime I'm not able to make it work no matter what I try. Why?!

```
var date = new DateTime(2010, 5, 21, 11, 30, 00);
AddFooToDb(new Foo { Text = date.ToString() } ); // Will add it to the database...

var result = Session
    .CreateCriteria<Foo>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.DateTime, Projections.Property("Text")), date))
    .List<Foo>();
```

Comment: Is it the format of the date? Try formatting the date.ToString() to "dd MMMM yyyy" and see. Not sure, I havent tried, just a thought

Comment: That is going to be a major pain in the ass if you need to cast before querying. If you really need it, I'd consider adding a column to store the actual type. That way you can make sure your cast will work.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how I can make sure the cast works if I know the type? Cause I will know the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Projections.Cast` executes in the DB, your RDBMS probably doesn't like the format stored by `date.ToString()`.

A quick fix that will also be easier in the DB is doing the conversion in the client instead:

```
.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Text", date.ToString()))
```

Now, in order for those dates to be used in sorting or range expressions, you need to make sure the format is appropriate.

So, instead of using `.ToString()`, which also has the problem of changing according to the current culture, use `.ToString("o")` or `.ToString("s")`.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good tip. However, I guess this won't work if I want to check e.g. a date between dateA and dateB? Or - if the date-string is built from most to least significant I guess it would.. Gotta do some testing with this.

Comment: Anyway - do you know what it would take to make the cast work? I'm currently using SQLite - will the format of the string depend on the type of database I'm using? I thought NHibernate was here to handle this gap for me?

Comment: NHibernate can't magically convert your .NET-formatted strings to the date format that SQLite uses. See my additions for a solution to the `between` issue.